# how to convert json data into BPMN compatible format?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, statechart, gojs

I am using [state chart supported by gojs](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html) library.

This library use JSON data to draw the diagram on canvas. Whatever diagram we draw, node and link are getting arranged into JSON data format.
I want to convert this data into [BMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Language) to utilize this diagram in another tool.

- Is it possible to convert this JSON data into [BMPN](http://www.bpmn.org/)? If yes, how can I
  do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not an expert on BPMN or BPML, but I believe BPML was a proposed standard that never really for off the ground about 11 years ago.  I guess there may be some vendors that have something they call BPML that they can import.  So... the first thing you need is a detailed specification of what this "other tool" supports.

Now... you don't say whether you want to do this JSON > BPML client or server side. Client side you can handle the JSON with JS easily enough, or just use the GoJS data model directly.

Server side, you'll need a parser like Json.NET or (for Java) see [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java).  Once you have the JSON as objects, it's just a matter of traversing the graph and generating the appropriate BPML.

Answer (score 0):

I think the format in which BPMN is described is XML. See [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_BRMS_Platform/5/html/BRMS_Business_Process_Management_Guide/An_Example_BPMN_2.0_Process.html) for more information about this format. But I don't think you are able a State Chart format easily to BPMN as this is relation based and BPMN also needs the location and waypoints of the objects and references in it's XML.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find any parser yet, but there is a [library](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-cli) by using that you can dynamically create bpmn components

Comment: affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)